# Android tablets with low density, how to use hdpi bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap, tablet

I'm developing a game. So far I tested it on different phones and it looked as expected.
But since I tried it on an Android tablet, I'm a litte confused about the right usage of the device density.
I have a tablet (HannsPad) with a big 10.1 inches screen and a resolution of 1024x600 pixels. The tablet runs with low dpi of 120. 
This causes my game to scale down all bitmaps from drawable-hdpi folder to ldpi size. As result the game looks awful on the big tablet screen. Additionaly the game itself is scaled by 0.5 (as the bitmaps) and it appears very small on the screen.

Any suggestions how I can force to not scale down hdpi bitmaps to ldpi size on a ldpi device or any other solution would help me a lot!

I rooted my tablet so I could change the density of the tablet from 120 to 240. Then the game looked as it should. But this is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the `res/drawable-ldpi/` folder entirely? After all, why are you putting resources there that you specifically do not ever want to use?

Comment: @CommonsWare Due to your question I realized that my question was wrong. I don't have actually bitmaps in drawable-ldpi. The game scales down on loading the bitmaps to a ldpi size. I'll overwork my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use `-large` for tablet's drawables ?

I suggest you add the following folders:

- `drawable-ldpi-small` : for low density phones.
- `drawable-ldpi-large` : for low density tablets

I guess this will work. Good luck !

Comment: It tells me "invalid resource directory name drawable-ldpi-large".  I'm using Android 1.6, API 4

Comment: The same error with API 10 (2.3). Do I have to register somewhere the new folder?

Comment: Oh it should be drawable-large-ldpi!

Comment: it works! thank you! But now I have the same bitmaps in two folder. Is there a way to "link" the bitmaps from drawable-hdpi to drawable-large-ldpi?

Comment: Here is a trick described to solve multiple bitmaps: http://blog.evendanan.net/2011/03/Android-resources-and-device-fragmentation

Comment: Beware, from Android version 3.2 `small`, `normal`, `large`, `xlarge`  qualifiers are deprecated!